# drop_duplicates() stopped working in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, drop-duplicates

This code had previously worked in python 3 to remove the duplicate values but keep first occurrence across an entire dataframe. After coming back to my script this no longer removes duplicates in a pandas dataFrame.

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(), axis=1)
```

so if I have

```
a   b  c
0   1  2
3   4  0
0   8  9
10  0  11
```

I want to get as an output

```
a  b  c
0  1  2
3  4  
   8  9
10   11
```

I don't mind if the blanks return as 'nan'

I also tried the following

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = None, keep='first')
```

and

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = None, keep='first', inplace =True)
```

Any advice / alternatives would be welcome!

Comment: First occurrence traversing row-wise or column-wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your attached the data , I think you can using `duplicated`

```
newdf=df[~df.stack().duplicated().unstack()]
newdf
Out[131]: 
      a    b     c
0   0.0  1.0   2.0
1   3.0  4.0   NaN
2   NaN  8.0   9.0
3  10.0  NaN  11.0
```

Comment: this worked great with the data converted to int64 - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need `inplace` to be True:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Comment: aah yes, I had tried True to update that frame too - edited Question